# Javascript- cannot read property value of null

Tags: mysql, node.js, global-variables

How can I get the value of id 'nilai' in another function?

```
var sis = 'SELECT nis, nama_siswa FROM nilai_tugas';

        connection.query(sis, function(err, rows, cols) {
            if(err){
                console.log("An error ocurred performing the query.");
                console.log(err);
                return;
            }else{console.log("sukses mengambil data siswa dari nilai_tugas")}
            var html='';
            rows.forEach(function(row){
              html += '<tr>';
              html += '<td class="indi" align="center">';
              html += row.nis;
              html += '</td>';
              html += '<td class="indi">';
              html += row.nama_siswa;
              html += '</td>';
              html += '<td>';
              html += '<input id="nilai" type="text" placeholder="nilai"/>';
              html += '</td>';
              html += '</tr>';  

            })
            var a=html.toUpperCase();
            document.querySelector('#table>tbody').innerHTML = a;
          })
```

I have tried with this in other function, but error 'cannot read property value of `null`'

```
var data1 = document.getElementById("nilai").value;
```

Comment: id "nilai" is not there in your html DOM.

Answer (score 1):

**You made a big mistake here,**

var a= html<del>.toUpperCase()</del>;

this make all html codes to Upper Case, so your Id also now became,

**"NILAI"** and ids are case sensitive.

don't use `.toUpperCase();`
simply store it as

```
var a = html;
```

Answer (score 0):

this error occurs when you don't have that object in the first place. so, probably the problem is that a DOM node with id 'nilai' does not exist at all. I think you are trying to get the value of 'nilai' input before it is rendered.